# On MAC OS X 10.11.4 - Loss of extended file attribute when copying a file

Tags: cp, macintosh, xattr, osx-finder

I have a file with a comment as extended attribute. This is how
I can see the attribute from the Terminal:
    `mdls -name kMDItemFinderComment path_to_file`
I get the answer
    `kMDItemFinderComment = "my_comment"`

To copy this file to new_location while preserving this comment, I type
    `cp -p path_to_file new_location`
Everything seems to work as typing
    `mdls -name kMDItemFinderComment new_location`
returns
    `kMDItemFinderComment = "my_comment"`

My problem arises when I access the copied file at the new_location from a Finder window. I click on Get Info but the Comments section is empty. After this action, when I try again
    `mdls -name kMDItemFinderComment new_location`
I get
    `kMDItemFinderComment = (null)`

Can anyone help me?

PS: should I use xattr?

Comment: I get the same result as you with `Get Info`, but `mdls` and `xattr` still show the comment.

Comment: It looks like the comments get cached in the folder's `.DS_Store` file, which isn't updated by `cp`. See http://superuser.com/questions/82106/where-does-spotlight-store-its-metadata-index

Comment: I only get the `(null)` if I do `Get Info` and then click on the comment field.